# How can I avoid mud from splashing onto my back without a rear wheel fender?

Tags: off-road, fenders

I enjoy cycling off-road. During rainy season, the cycling trails can get muddy. Most of the bikes from rental shops do not come with a rear mudguard. I tried to slow down and avoid puddles of water, but it seems inevitable that blotches of mud would stain the back of my shirt at the end of the day.

Are there better methods of avoiding mud from splashing onto my back?

Comment: They have mud guards that attach to the seat post. Don't know if that would qualify as a "fender" but they are a lot easier to put on and remove, and you don't have to worry about wheel/frame clearance.

Comment: Don't ride in the mud.

Comment: Wear an old t shirt and take it off after the ride.

Comment: There's a neat little thing called ass-savers (google) It fits to the rails of the saddle (in your pocket as well) and it's up to the name!

Comment: I would just accept the fact that you will get wet and dirty if you want to ride off-road when it is wet; that is one of the pleasure of the sport!!!

Comment: I don't think anyone has yet pointed out that biking slower through the mud would prevent it from being flung.

Comment: @Carel, thanks for the [ass saving](http://ass-savers.com/) :) This is the kind of stuff that I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a seatpost-mounted rear mudguard, like the SKS X-tra Dry:

[image]

For the front, you can also use a downtube mudguard like the SKS X-board:

[image]

These are convenient for bikes which don't have proper fender mounts/fenders would interfere with clearance/fenders need to be easily removed or not [Most mountain bikes fit this thing]. They don't protect the drivetrain from crud thrown up from the wheels so they aren't great for improving drivetrain life on a road bike, but this is not a concern for your riding.

The other option is to wear clothes you don't mind getting dirty.

Comment: Do my eyes deceive me, or in the second picture does it appear that simply turning the front wheel is enough for the crud to bypass the mudguard?

Comment: That's the way they're supposed to function -- its not perfect, but at those angles, crud won't really be thrown primarily in the direction of the rider. These are primarily for cases where you can't mount a regular fender (in the case of a mountain bike, it would be dangerous since it gives one extra place for something to jam into your wheel).